# How do i convert 3D list in python to csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a 3D list like

```
final_arr = [[[1,2,3,4],2],[[1,1,2,2],3],[[1,2,2],4]]
```

Now I want to convert each row into csv column, like for first list item the columns should be `1 2 3 4 2` in csv single row and multiple columns.

Right now I am doing this but the whole list is becoming single column in csv:

```
import csv

with open("out1.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(final_arr)
```

Comment: just do `for record, item in finall_arr: writer.writerow([*record, item])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is objective something like this:

```py
final_arr = [[[1,2,3,4],2],[[1,1,2,2],3],[[1,2,2],4]]


with open('out1.csv', 'w') as f:
    for (i, j) in final_arr:
        print(*i, j, file=f)

# out1.csv
1 2 3 4 2
1 1 2 2 3
1 2 2 4
```

EDIT: as suggested by @juanpa.arrivillaga same approach with using csv module and `writerow`:

```
import csv

with open('out1.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=" ")
    for (i, j) in final_arr:
        writer.writerow((*i, j))
```

and with `writerows`:

```
with open('out1.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=" ")
    writer.writerows((*i, j) for (i, j) in final_arr)
```

Comment: you should use the `csv` module to create csvs

Answer (score 0):

As an extension of Aivar's answer,

Your list is not a 3D list. It is a 2D list where elements can be an array. For the provided array, we can apply this Alvar's answer. You may want to add a separator while printing inside the file.

```
final_arr = [[[1,2,3,4],2],[[1,1,2,2],3],[[1,2,2],4]]

with open('out1.csv', 'w') as f:
    for (i, j) in final_arr:
        print(*i, j, file=f, sep=',')
```

Comment: this answer should use the `csv` module

Comment: This should have been a comment on @AivarPaalberg's answer, not a stand-alone answer.